# Unable to figure out a way to make the last IF condition dynamic in Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a QUERY function that is not doing what I expect. The references, such as `B4`, are check boxes. What I am stuck with is the last condition, as soon as the last `B6` checkbox is unchecked (`FALSE`), it gives an error and stops working. QUERY Formula is in Sheet 2.
[Sample sheeet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mePVjKKPWXlee_ozjxs5ow--GWOfheWAZ4-1tU2MRVI/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:F, "SELECT A,
"& IF(Sheet2!A2=TRUE, "D,","") &" 
"& IF(Sheet2!B2=TRUE, "E,","") &" 
"& IF(Sheet2!C2=TRUE, "F","") &"
WHERE A is not null", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comma positioning is causing the issue. Try the below formula and notice that the comma is always behind the letter. This will always mean that the final column will not have a comma. The way you have it now it's expecting another column EXCEPT when you check `C` and then it properly recognizes the transition to your `where` statement. See sample spreadsheet I put in your sheet.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:F, "SELECT A
    "& IF(pgsystemtesterWorksheet!A2=TRUE, ",D","") &" 
    "& IF(pgsystemtesterWorksheet!B2=TRUE, ",E","") &" 
    "& IF(pgsystemtesterWorksheet!C2=TRUE, ",F","") &"
    WHERE A is not null", 1)
```

[image: Example Result]

Comment: that simple?!!! woah! I have been trying to make it work, trying multiple different formulas.
Thank you so much! :)